# IntelliSense for method accepting Expression parameter with Func overload

Tags: c#, intellisense, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack OrmLite's Select method can accept `Expression<Func<MyTable,bool>>` as parameter. It can also accept `Func` as parameter. I prefer to use the Expression parameter but the VisualStudio's intellisense always think that I am typing the Func parameter:

```
var connstr = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=mydb";
var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connstr, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
using (var db = factory.Open())
{
    // using the Func<<SqlExpressionVisitor<MyTable>,SqlExpressionVisitor<MyTable>> overload
    var withvisitor = db.Select<MyTable>(v => v.Where(t => t.ID == 42));

    // using the Expression<Func<MyTable,bool>> overload
    // but the intellisense is still for the Func overload
    var withoutvisitor = db.Select<MyTable>(t => t.ID == 42);
}
```

Is there a way to tell VisualStudio that I want to use the Expression overload instead of the Func one (for intellisense)?

Comment: I end up always using the visitor overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio 2015. It is smart enough to detect that you intend to key in expression.